# Regex multiple string company abbreviations

Tags: regex

We have a problem validating company abbreviations.
The input strings are made up of `n` asterisks at the beginning and end and in the middle by two or more capital letters with a period immediately after each one.

Valid input strings are:

```
 - *S.A.*
 - M.A.S.H.

 - *X.Y.*
```

NOT valid input strings are:

```
 - *A.*
 - P.I.B
 - *ETC...*
```

It is in regular expression with which I do my tests:
`^\*+[A-Z]+\.[A-Z]+\.\*+$`

thanks for your support
[image]

Comment: What are the actual rules here?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem attached the answer for future searches

^\*+([A-Z](\.[A-Z])+)\.\*+$

Comment: This expression doesn't look right though... You probably meant to escape `*` and use `*` instead of '+' after the asterisks.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect any number of `*` before and after the abbreviation:

```
^[*]*([A-Z]+\.){2,}[*]*$
```

Asterisk are optional (that way `M.A.S.H.` is valid as well) and the repetition of 2 to any number of times of `[A-Z]+\.` makes it match with longer abbreviations

Link to regex101: https://regex101.com/r/BfowgA/1

Comment: Either `[*]` *or* `\*` is sufficient.

Comment: You're right! I'm going for `[*]` since `\**` doesn't look pretty at all ;-)